# Trouble with ionic proxy

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to set up the ionic proxy for live reload. It however fails for an (to me) unclear reason:

Request URL:

```
`/php/getData.php`

`ionic.config.json`
```

```

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/php",
      "proxyUrl": "https://mydomain/php"
    }
  ]
}
```

```

Connect to iOS Simulator with debugger, if fails with:

`

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://192.168.0.20:8100/php/getData.php
>   `

Why does the system translate it to the local ip instead of the domain name? Is there a way to troubleshoot this or debug?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the proxy work in the browser when you do ionic serve?

Comment: I have to use the proxy because I added the native Google Maps and have now to run everything with live-reload, can't run `serve`. Before that I always was running in the browser.

Comment: I remember I couldn't get ionic proxy to work with live reload when running on the device, had to resort to other solutions.

Comment: I'm running live-reload in the simulator. But interesting, what would "other solutions" be in this case?

Comment: So we have a public domain `example.com` that's configured through an apache server. I added a proxy that points `example.com/test-api` to point to the IP address of my computer. Then if the client app is running dev mode on the device, I point to `example.com/test-api` instead of `example.com/api`.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I was as well thinking to create an apache proxy address on my dev machine.